# How to make @login_required optional

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a django web page which I want  to display to every user irrespective of whether he is logged in or not.

In view of the django project I have added the decorator @login_required

```
    @login_required(login_url='/login')
    def home(request):
       current_user = str(request.user)
       data = {}
       data['current_user'] = current_user
```

which makes the user to redirect to login page.

But since I want the user to view the data even though he is not logged in and open a pop up(model) for login on same page if he wish to login.

So I removed the @login_required directive. But when user tries to login it fails with following error:

```
    username = request.POST['username']
File "/home/jay/jay/at_jay/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "'username'"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Full traceback:

```
inside login block Internal Server Error: /login/ Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   
File "site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/jay/jay/AutoTriage/dashboard/views.py", line 160, in login_user
  username = request.POST['username']   
File "site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
  raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key)) MultiValueDictKeyError: "'username'" [16/Mar/2016 13:58:46] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 67952
```

Comment: Could you show view?

Comment: please post the full traceback

Comment: `request.POST` will be filled only on POST-request (via forms for example), if you want only show data, use GET-requests. Also be ready that user could be Anonymouse.

Comment: @JK_Jha: yes File "/home/jay/jay/AutoTriage/dashboard/views.py", line 160 up and below 50 lines. Or function `login_user`

Comment: Here is the tht function: https://anotepad.com/notes/k63qrc

Comment: Thanks. I quite agree with colleagues: it's better to use standard methods. But if you wish do it youself, you need to work with emply POSTs, try to use `.get()` method. Or: `if 'username' in request.POST: ....` do authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to handle both logged in and not logged in user. You can do this by using Django's `AnonymousUser` class and `request.user.is_authenticated`

See [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/17/django-sessions-part-iii-user-authentication) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Django comes with [built in authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). I recommend you use them, rather than writing your own views to login.

If you don't use them, it's good practice to use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/), instead of fetching data directly from `request.POST`.

If you insist on fetching data from `request.POST`, you need to handle the case when the key does not exist. You can either do this by checking whether the key exists,

```
if 'username' in request.POST:
    username = request.POST['username']
else:
    # do something else
```

or by using the `get()` method.

```
username = request.POST.get('username', 'default')
```